# How do I find a value in a column that just have unique values with EclipseLink?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink

You have the `EntityManager.find(Class entityClass, Object primaryKey)` method to find a specific row with a primary key.

But how do I find a value in a column that just have unique values and is not a primary key?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For example, like this:

```
List<T> results = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM TABLE t", T.class)
                        .getResultList();
```

With parameters:

```
List<T> results = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM TABLE t where t.value = :value1")
                        .setParameter("value1", "some value").getResultList();
```

For single result replace `getResultList()` with `getSingleResult()`:

```
T entity = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM TABLE t where t.uniqueKey = :value1")
                 .setParameter("value1", "KEY1").getSingleResult();
```

One other way is to use Criteria API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew I could do it with a query, I was just wondering if I could do it faster with less code by using a method of the JPA, like `EntityManager.find()`.

Answer (score 16):

You can use appropriate JPQL with [TypedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html).

```
try {
    TypedQuery<Bean> tq = em.createQuery("from Bean WHERE column=?", Bean.class);
    Bean result = tq.setParameter(1, "uniqueKey").getSingleResult();
} catch(NoResultException noresult) {
    // if there is no result
} catch(NonUniqueResultException notUnique) {
    // if more than one result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Query, either JPQL, Criteria, or SQL.

Not sure if your concern is in obtaining cache hits similar to find().  In EclipseLink 2.4 cache indexes were added to allow you to index non-primary key fields and obtain cache hits from JPQL or Criteria.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Indexes

Prior to 2.4 you could use in-memory queries to query the cache on non-id fields.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

With in DSL level - [JPA](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html) no practice mentioned in previous answers

> How do I find a value in a column that just have unique values and is not a primary key?

There isn't specification for query with custom field with in root interface of `javax.persistence.EntityManager`, you need to have [criteria](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-criteria.htm) base query.

```html
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<R> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(EntityType.class)
Root<R> root = criteriaQuery.from(type);
criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(your_field), value));
```

You can also group your predicates together and pass them all together.

```
andPredicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(root.get(field).in(child)));
criteriaBuilder.and(andPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{});
```

And calling result(rather single entity or a list of entities) with

```
entityManager.createQuery(suitable_criteria_query).getSingleResult();
entityManager.createQuery(suitable_criteria_query).getResultList();
```